# Sending log output to Sentry

Tags: logging, kubernetes, sentry

I currently have a php-fpm container set up in Kubernetes to output error messages, exceptions,... to stderr. This way I can see my PHP errors, when using 'kubectl logs'.

I'm also working with sentry and I was wondering if there was a good way to collect my log output and send it to sentry, so I can use sentry to see my errors as well. I'm not looking to change the code though, so using php and some specific logger to send messages to sentry directly won't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Fluentd**](https://www.fluentd.org/) with [an output plugin](https://www.fluentd.org/plugins/all) that sends aggregated errors/exception events to **Sentry** e.g. [this one](https://github.com/y-ken/fluent-plugin-sentry).

**Fluentd** is deployed as a sidecar container in your app `Pod` so you don't have to change anything in your code.